How do I use Google's Gemini with a large amount of external data quickly?
I am using Gemini to analyze a vast amount of feedback data from customers. I want to ask the model questions like "what are the most common complaints?" and "what do customers like about our services?".
I am currently just prefixing the prompt with the relevant data but this is slow and often throws errors when the data is too large.
Fine tuning sounds like the way to go but I only have the raw data, not a list of inputs/outputs for the model to train on. Is there a way to fine tune the model with just all the data? Or is there another way to change the state of the model to allow for faster prompt responses?
Note that I have also tried RAG architecture, but this does not seem very useful in that I am already providing a subset of the data (and do not need semantic querying on the data).

Although I'm not sure whether my proposal approach is your expected direction, I posted it as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

I'm unsure whether this approach is ideal for your specific situation. Therefore, consider it as one of several options available.
Simple Approach: Corpus and generateAnswer
This approach utilizes a corpus and the generateAnswer function for a straightforward solution. Currently, a corpus can hold a maximum of 1 million chunks. If your "vast amount of customer feedback data" is less than 1 million entries, this method might be able to be used. Here's the workflow:

Create a Corpus Ref
Create a Document Ref
Add Customer Feedback Data: Split your "vast amount of customer feedback data" into chunks and add them to the document. Ref
Analyze Feedback: Use the semanticRetriever of the models.generateAnswer function to answer questions like "what are the most common complaints?" or "what do customers like about our services?" Ref.

The chunks are retained, allowing you to incorporate new data and generate answers using the entire dataset.
Of course, you can manage the corpus and chunks. You can see the official document. Ref And, as a simple sample, you can simply test it using a Google Apps Script library. Ref
References:

Method: corpora.create
Method: corpora.documents.create
Method: corpora.documents.chunks.batchCreate
Method: models.generateAnswer
CorporaApp (Author: me)

